# Structural induction haskell

Tags: haskell, map-function, induction

I would like to know how I can show in structural induction that list xs , or how the induction work in this:

```
map f (map g xs) = map (\x -> f(g x)) xs
```

with this function definition

```
  map :: ( a -> b ) -> [ a ] -> [ b ]

  map _ [] = []

  map f ( x : xs ) = f x : map f xs
```

Is it like the math induction or not ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Structural induction is a generalization of the mathematical notion of induction. Mathematical induction works specifically over natural numbers and splits the situation into two cases: the case where the number is zero, and the case where it's one bigger than any other number. Specifically, this corresponds to the [Peano definition of natural numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peano_axioms), which can be written in Haskell as follows.

```
data Nat = Zero | Succ Nat
```

So an inductive proof over this data type splits into two cases, one for each type constructor. The first says "assume we have a `Zero`; prove it". The second says "assume we have a `Succ n` where the work is already done for `n`; now prove it".

Now you want to prove something inductively over lists. The list type can be written (modulo syntax sugar) as

```
data [a] = [] | a : [a]
```

to be perfectly precise, this corresponds to the following (magic-free) definition

```
data List a = Nil | Cons a (List a)
```

though I'll use the first one, since it's a little cleaner to work with in Haskell. A structural induction proof over `[a]` shall be split into two cases:

- Assume the list is empty. Prove the statement.
- Assume the list is non-empty and whatever we wanted to prove is true for the tail. Prove the statement for the whole list.

So let's apply that to `map`. Here's your `map` function.

```
map :: (a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]
map _ [] = []
map f (x : xs) = f x : map f xs
```

and the thing we want to prove is, written precisely:

> Let `f :: b -> c` and `g :: a -> b` be arbitrary functions. Then prove that, for any list `xs :: [a]`, we have
>
> ```
> map f (map g xs) = map (\y -> f (g y)) xs
> ```

Let's begin. There are two cases. First, assume `xs` is empty, i.e. `xs == []`. Then, straight from the function definition above, we know `map g xs == map g [] == []` and the same for `f`, so we have the following equivalences

```
map f (map g [])
map f []
[]
map (\y -> f (g y)) []
```

Each of these deductions follows from the definition of `map`, since we have a complete understanding of what `map` does to the empty list (namely, it doesn't do anything, and the function makes no difference). So the first case is complete.

Now, the inductive step. Assume we have a list `(x : xs)`, and assume the statement is true for `xs`. So we're *assuming*

```
map f (map g xs) == map (\y -> f (g y)) xs
```

and we want to prove

```
map f (map g (x : xs)) == map (\y -> f (g y)) (x : xs)
```

So let's proceed step-by-step.

```
map f (map g (x : xs))
map f (g x : map g xs)           -- By the function definition
f (g x) : map f (map g xs)       -- By the function definition
f (g x) : map (\y -> f (g y)) xs -- By induction hypothesis
map (\y -> f (g y)) (x : xs)     -- By the function definition
```

Hence, the statement holds.

By structural induction, the statement holds for `[]` and, assuming the statement holds for `xs`, it holds for `x : xs` as well. Hence, we can conclude that it holds for all finite lists.

Structural induction is *not* powerful enough to prove that it holds for infinite lists. Haskell's `[a]` type (and indeed Haskell in general) is a weird mix of induction and coinduction that makes a formal mathematical proof of this a bit awkward. Going strictly by the inductive definition, the type `[a]` should *not* have any infinite cases, so we shan't worry about them for the purposes of this proof.

Comment: How did induction over natural numbers come to be called "mathematical induction" when its generalizations (induction over ordinals, structural induction, and wellfounded induction) are every bit as mathematical?

Comment: @dfeuer Probably because it's what's taught in math classes. I've seen math professors at the college level bend over backward to perform natural number induction when much better tools are available. I died a little inside every time my math prof would write a proof of the form "Proceed by induction on the depth of this tree. If the depth is > 1, then we must not be a leaf node". But it seems, at least to me, that lots of pure mathematicians (specifically, algebraists) are not as aware of structural induction as we would ideally like them to be.